# How do you make it so that this code is toggleable?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

target_channel_id = 869727547221475388
role_id = #write role ID here
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@tasks.loop(minutes=40)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ping_start():
    message_channel = client.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    role = message_channel.guild.get_role(role_id)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel}")
    await message_channel.send(role.mention)

@ping_start.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

ping_start.start()

client.run("TOKEN")
```

I found this code somewhere else on this site. It basically pings a certain role every 40 minutes. The thing is, I want to make it so that when you type a command in the chat, it starts timing. And you can also stop this with a different command. How would I do that?

Edit: Tried this code but the output says "Line 81 name 'remindcmd' is used prior to global declaration". I know what this means but don't know how to fix it since it looks like everything should work.

```
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
  format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
  level=logging.INFO,
)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")


# target_channel_id = 1052266313734697041
# role_id = 1052265314269798400
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")

global remindcmd
remindcmd = "neither"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.__contains__("!!listen"):
          await message.channel.send("Listening for command input.")
          print("!!listen command detected.")

  if message.content.__contains__("!!test"):
          global remindcmd
          await message.channel.send(f"!!test {remindcmd}")

  if message.content.startswith("!!"):
    if message.content.endswith("/"):
      if message.content.startswith("!!reverse/"):
          revmsg = message.content[message.content.find("/")+1:-1]
          await message.channel.send(revmsg[::-1])
  
      if message.content.startswith("!!saysecretcmd/"):
        print(message.content[15:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)])
        message_channel = client.get_channel(int(message.content[15:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]))
        print(f"Got channel {message_channel} !!saysecretcmd")
        saymsg = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:-1]
        print(f"Said the message, {saymsg}")
        await message_channel.send(saymsg)
      
      if message.content.startswith("!!remind/"):
        if not message.content.startswith("!!remind/stop/"):
      
          arg1 = message.content[9:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]
          arg2 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)]
          arg3 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)]
          arg4 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1)]
          arg5 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)]
          print(arg1)
          print(arg2)
          print(arg3)
          print(arg4)
          print(arg5)
      
          if arg2 == "false":
            print("Unlooped")
            #time.sleep(arg1)
        
          else:
            print("Looped")
            print(arg1)
            print(arg2)
            print(arg3)
            print(arg4)
            print(arg5)
            print("arg variables printed")

            @tasks.loop(seconds=int(arg1))
            async def ping_start(message, target_channel_id, role_id):
              print("Entered async ping start")
              global remindcmd
              print(remindcmd)
              message_channel = client.get_channel(int(target_channel_id))
              role = message_channel.guild.get_role(int(role_id))
              if remindcmd == "false":
                global remindcmd
                print("Stopped")
                ping_start.cancel()
                await message_channel.send("Loop stopped.")
                remindcmd = "neither"
                print("remindcmd variable set to neither")
              print(f"Got channel {message_channel} !!remind")
              await message_channel.send(message.replace("{role}", role.mention))
              remindcmd = "true"
              print(remindcmd)
              
              @ping_start.before_loop
              async def before():
                await client.wait_until_ready()
                print("Finished waiting")
              
            ping_start.start(arg3, arg4, arg5)
      
      if message.content.startswith("!!remind/stop/"):
        print("Stop command detected")
        global remindcmd
        print(remindcmd)
        remindcmd = "false"
        print(remindcmd)
        print("remindcmd variable set to false")
          
# await message.channel.send("Message here")

keep_alive()
my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: you would have to poll the chat for incoming messages and if the message that you want is said then you would activate `ping_start.start()` and if there is a closing message you would check and try to stop it (which this code does not have at the current moment)

Comment: I've been trying to do that but I don't know how. My new code is edited into the post.